# Can someone help me look at this SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, temp-tables

I'm trying to create a temporary table in `SQL`, but there is an error that I can't recognize.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Guest(ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ticket_id NOT NULL VARCHAR(255),
event_id NOT NULL INT (11),
user_id NOT NULL INT (11),
fullname NOT NULL VARCHAR(255),
delivery NOT NULL VARCHAR(255),
ticket_type NOT NULL VARCHAR(255),
ticket_price NOT NULL DECIMAL(19,4),
fees NOT NULL DECIMAL(19,4),
total_price NOT NULL DECIMAL(19,4),
barcode NOT NULL VARCHAR(255),
purchase_time NOT NULL datatime,
person_pickup NOT NULL varchar(80),
Qty NOT NULL INT(11));
```

Here is the error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to usenear 'NOT NULL VARCHAR(255),event_id NOT NULL INT (11),user_id NOTNULL INT (11),fulln' at line 1
```

Comment: try to remove the spaces between INT and (11) for event_id and user_id

Comment: @LelioFaieta That doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - Put the "NOT NULL" after the field types:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Guest(ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ticket_id  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
event_id  INT (11) NOT NULL,
user_id  INT (11) NOT NULL,
fullname  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
delivery  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ticket_type  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ticket_price  DECIMAL(19,4) NOT NULL,
fees  DECIMAL(19,4) NOT NULL,
total_price  DECIMAL(19,4) NOT NULL,
barcode  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
purchase_time  datetime NOT NULL,
person_pickup  varchar(80) NOT NULL,
Qty  INT(11) NOT NULL);
```

2 - You had a typo on "DATETIME"